# unable to resolve ssh class in gradle.build

Tags: gradle, groovy, gradle-plugin

I am trying to invoke a custom groovy plugin from gradle build file. But I am getting the error while resolving the classes for ssh. Below is the build file, part of custom groovy plugin and the error.

build.gradle

```
plugins {
  id 'org.sonarqube' version '2.0.1'
  id 'groovy'
  id 'org.hidetake.ssh' version'2.7.0'
}

dependencies {
    compile gradleApi()
    compile localGroovy()
}
```

CustPlugin.groovy

```
package com.nielsen.gradle

import org.slf4j.Logger
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat

import org.gradle.api.Project
import org.gradle.api.Plugin
import org.gradle.api.GradleException
import org.gradle.api.plugins.BasePlugin
import org.gradle.api.tasks.bundling.Zip

import org.hidetake.groovy.ssh.Ssh.*
import org.hidetake.groovy.ssh.core.Service

import com.nielsen.gradle.cmRegistry.CMRegistryPlugin
```

Error

```
C:\Users\528302\Documents\gradle_all\projectf1>gradle build
:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
:compileGroovy
startup failed:
C:\Users\528302\Documents\gradle_all\projectf1\src\main\groovy\com\nielsen\gradle\CustPlugin.groovy: 14: unable to resolve class org.hidetake.groovy.ssh.Ssh
 @ line 14, column 1.
   import org.hidetake.groovy.ssh.Ssh
   ^

C:\Users\528302\Documents\gradle_all\projectf1\src\main\groovy\com\nielsen\gradle\CustPlugin.groovy: 15: unable to resolve class org.hidetake.groovy.ssh.core.Service

 @ line 15, column 1.
   import org.hidetake.groovy.ssh.core.Service
   ^

C:\Users\528302\Documents\gradle_all\projectf1\src\main\groovy\com\nielsen\gradle\CustPlugin.groovy: 17: unable to resolve class com.nielsen.gradle.cmRegistry.CMRegi
stryPlugin
 @ line 17, column 1.
   import com.nielsen.gradle.cmRegistry.CMRegistryPlugin
   ^
```

Please help resolving this...Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mixing two things. By using the `plugins { }` closure you are adding dependencies for the buildscript itself. But in this case the code you are building has a dependency on some library, not the buildscript.

Try to add the following into `dependencies { }`

`compile group: 'org.hidetake', name: 'groovy-ssh', version: '2.8.0'`

so you end up having

```
plugins {
  id 'org.sonarqube' version '2.0.1'
  id 'groovy'
  id 'org.hidetake.ssh' version'2.7.0'
}

dependencies {
    compile gradleApi()
    compile localGroovy()
    compile group: 'org.hidetake', name: 'groovy-ssh', version: '2.8.0'
}
```

Comment: Thanks Martin...I tried but I am getting the follwoing error:

   * What went wrong:
    Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':compileClasspath'.
    > Cannot resolve external dependency org.hidetake:groovy-ssh:1.1.6 because no repositories are defined.
      Required by:
          project :

Comment: Same for version 2.8.0

Comment: Now you are missing repositories declaration.

add 

`repositories {
mavenCentral()
}`

to your `build.gradle`

Comment: It worked...Thanks Martin...can you please help resolving for this --> gradle.cmRegistry.CMRegistryPlugin

Comment: You are welcome. Please accept the answer in case it helped you.